# Automate server setup with Ansible SSH keypairs fails without sshpass

Tags: ansible

I'm am using Ansible and want to automate my VPS & Homelab setups. I'm running into an issue, which is the initial connection.

If I have a fresh VPS that has never been used or logged into, how can I remotely configure the node from my laptop?

#### ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventory
remote_user = root
host_key_checking = false
ansible_ssh_common_args = "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

#### inventory

```
[homelab]
0.0.0.0 <--- actual IP here
```

#### ./playbooks/add_pub_keys.yaml

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install public key on remote node
      authorized_key:
        state: present
        user: root
        key: "{{lookup('file','~/.ssh/homelab.pub')}}"
```

##### Command

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/add_public_keys.yaml
```

Now, this fails with permission denied, which makes sense because there is nothing that would allow connection to the remote node.

I tried adding `-ask-pass` to the command:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/add_public_keys.yaml -ask-pass
```

and typing in the *root* password, but that fails and says I need `sshpass`, which is not recommended and not readily available to install on Mac due to security. How should I think about this initial setup process?

Comment: You either install sshpass or find an other way than Ansicble to copy your key to the target.

Answer (score -1):

When I get issues like this I try and replicate the problem using ansible ad-hoc commands and go back to basics. It helps to prove where the issue is located.

Are you able to run ansible ad-hoc commands against your remote server using the password?

```
ansible -i ip, all -m shell -a 'uptime' -u root -k
```

If you can't, something is up with the password or possible in the ansible.cfg.

Comment: Using a password for ssh with ansible requires sshpass on the controller, wherever you define that password (command line, inventory, play....)